The taxonomy tree is missing from the attachment first page (modal)
I've added a new taxonomy for medias but, the taxonomy is not showing correctly for hierarchical. It's show as a textbox on the popup/modal page (first page).
If we click "Edit more details", it goes to a different page, and then we can view the taxonomy tree.
See what I mean here: https://imgur.com/a/UqKiRzK
It seems like a minor issue, but it makes the process so much complicated for the client.
From this:
Media -> Click on Media -> Edit Taxonomy -> Click Next!
To this:
Media -> Click on Media -> Click on 'Edit more details' -> Edit taxonomy -> Click 'Update' -> Go back to media library -> Find last media (yikes for multiples pages!) to get the next

I ended up creating a new taxonomy field in addition to the new taxonomy. In the field options, you can sync it with the taxonomy of your choice. In the interface, you can then hide the real taxonomy, so only the new field is shown.
I got the idea from ACF Support team:

That section cannot show a taxonomy tree not because of ACF but
because of wordpress. The look of that area is determined by
wordpress, not ACF. If you need your users to see a hierarchy of sorts
for the taxonomies at that popup screen then you could use a taxonomy
field and set it to show up as a multi-select in the appearance
setting -
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/taxonomy/#settings. Its
not the same as for Edit more details   Hope this clears things up.

